# How to view SN history of the PWO?

Tags: sap-erp, serial-number

Is there a T-code or a table that can retrieve the history of multiple serial numbers along with the Production Work Order (PWO) associated to the Serial Numbers (SN)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1. Go to IQ02/IQ03 transaction aka "Change/View material serial" and enter the material and serial number
2. Click History button at the bottom of the SerData tab

[image]

3. Voila! You can see all the documents that are linked to this serial: notifications, orders, etc.

[image]